# Nameservers are not pointing to IP address but DNS records seem correct

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to get two name servers to work but am having a very difficult time. I have two servers, a master and slave, with hostnames ns3.example.com and ns4.example.com. The two ip addresses are: 21.117.15.20 and 21.117.15.21, respectively. I am using RedHat Linux. Finally, I have opened port 53, and installed dns service on both servers.

When I dig, or do nslookup on the hostnames, they appear to be pointing to the correct ip addresses. When I enter the ip addresses in the web browsers, the site loads for both servers. but the hostnames are not pointing to the respective ip addresses.

Here's the changes I made to /etc/named.conf, identified by #*****:

```
MASTER
======
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 21.117.15.20; }; #*****
#       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; }; #*****
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        allow-query     { localhost; 21.117.15.0/24; }; #*****
        allow-transfer { localhost; 21.117.15.21; }; #*****

SLAVE
=====
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 21.117.15.21; }; #*****
#       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; }; #*****
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        allow-query     { localhost; 21.117.15.0/24; }; #*****
```

I also added this to the /etc/named.conf:

```
MASTER
======
zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "forward.example";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "15.117.21.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "reverse.example";
        allow-update { none; };
};
SLAVE
=====
zone "example.com" IN {
        type slave;
        file "slaves/example.fwd.zone";
        masters { 21.117.15.20; };
};
zone "15.117.21.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type slave;
        file "slaves/example.rev.zone";
        masters { 21.117.15.20; };
};
```

Here's my forward zone file:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ns3.example.com. support.example.com. (
                                                2022070201  ;Serial
                                                3600        ;Refresh
                                                1800        ;Retry
                                                604800      ;Expire
                                                86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@ IN NS ns3.example.com.
@ IN NS ns4.example.com.

;IP Address for Name Server
ns3 IN A 21.117.15.20
ns4 IN A 21.117.15.21

;A Record for the following Host name
www                    IN   A   21.117.15.20
example.com.      3599 IN   A   21.117.15.20

;CNAME Record
ftp  IN   CNAME www.example.com.
```

I didn't include the mail server, because this is on another server. And finally, here is my reverse zone file:

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA ns3.example.com. support.example.com. (
                                                2022070201  ;Serial
                                                3600        ;Refresh
                                                1800        ;Retry
                                                604800      ;Expire
                                                86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@ IN NS ns3.example.com.
@ IN NS ns4.example.com.
ns3     IN  A   21.117.15.20
ns4     IN  A   21.117.15.21

;Reverse lookup for Name Server
20 IN PTR ns3.example.com.
21 IN PTR ns4.example.com.

;PTR Record IP address to Hostname
20  IN  PTR     example.com.
20  IN  PTR     www.example.com.
```

I used this same coding on another server, with the exception of the mail server, and it worked perfectly. I have been at this for several days, but nothing is working.

If someone could please tell me what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: "Opened a port 53" — did you open *both* TCP and UDP? DNS uses TCP for transfers and large queries, UDP for most queries. // Also, the behaviour of web browsers depends on both NS forward zone content (which looks correct) *and* the local resolver configuration. How is the DNS resolving configured on the machine where you run web browser? // The reverse zone is different beast; and it looks suboptimal. I mean, it is possible to have several PTRs for the same IP address, but it wouldn't work as you expected. Better choose one "canonical" name for each IP and only set one PTR record for it.

Comment: I have opened both ports 53. I think I may have found the problem. I had the domain running on a shared server with 4 other websites, and I think I may have gotten some conflicting data. I removed every trace of the domain I'm working with here from the shared server, and reconfigured the zone files by adding the email server. I even changed the hostnames from ns1 and ns2, to dns1 and dns2. I'll know in a few hours if it's working.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT. The reason it didn't work is because I was using a complicated configuration that was very confusing to me. So what I did was, configure the master server only with a configuration that worked for me before. And fortunately, it worked again. Then, I decided to tackle the slave server. I just added a few lines of code that I got from a YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foJDunPa1tY . Thank you all for your help.